# crystal report cross tab background color

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table that looks like this

```
category | number | month year | Color
-----------------------------------------------------
All      |  0.25  | YTD 2017   | 
Apple    |  1.23  | MAR 2017   | 
Orange   |  1.10  | FEB 2017   | 
Orange   |  3.33  | YTD 2017   | green
Apple    |  2.20  | FEB 2017   | 
Apple    |  1.11  | YTD 2017   | red
```

I want my cross tab to look like this

```
       |FEB 2017|MAR 2017|YTD 2017
-------------------------------------
Apple  | 2.20   |  1.23  | 1.11 (I want this cell to be red)
Orange | #.##   |  #.##  | 3.33 (I want this cell to be green)
All    | #.##   |  #.##  | #.##
```

what I have done so far is to have Color in the summarized fields.

it shows up the value as text. but I can't color it ... this is the formula for crosstab background color

```
if {table1.SColor} = "Green" then crGreen
else if {table1.SColor} = "Orange" then crRed
```

screenshot of current state.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with layering two crosstabs on top of each other. Credit to ckruger  http://www.infosol.com/crystal-reports-xi-r2-highlight-values-in-crosstabs/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR6JI.jpg

[image]
http://www.infosol.com/crystal-reports-xi-r2-highlight-values-in-crosstabs/